# Undefined issue for length in javascript

Tags: javascript

alert shows undefined.I have 3 textbox in my form and id's are same qty.
but it shows undefined of the length of id's of textbox.I want to add three column values and add show in another textbox.but the length shown is undefined.

```
<td><input class="text" type="text" name="qty1" id="qty" 
 onBlur="_leadingZero(this);_calcQty()" onKeyPress="return isNumber(event)" 
 style="background-color:#ffffff"></td>
<td><textarea  name="remarks1"  style="width:175;height:20"></textarea></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td class="formlabel" valign="center" style="text-align:center;background-
 color:#333333;color:#CCCCCC;font-weight:100">2nd</td>

<td><input class="text" type="text" name="qty2" id="qty"
  onBlur="_leadingZero(this);_calcQty()" onKeyPress="return isNumber(event)"
    style="background-color:#ffffff"></td>
    <td><textarea  name="remarks2"  style="width:175;height:20"></textarea>
  </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="formlabel" valign="center" style="text- 
   align:center;background-color:#333333;color:#CCCCCC;font-
   weight:100">3rd</td>


      <td><input class="text" type="text" name="qty3" id="qty"
    onBlur="_leadingZero(this);_calcQty()" onKeyPress="return
    isNumber(event)" style="background-color:#ffffff"></td>
    <td><textarea  name="remarks3"  style="width:175;height:20"></textarea>
    </td>




   function _calcQty()
    {
        var row=document.getElementById("qty");
        var sum = 0;
        alert(row);

        for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++)
        {
            if(parseInt(row[i].value))
                sum += parseInt(row[i].value);



        }



        document.all.total_qty.value=sum;
    }
```

Comment: From you code look like you new to JS. Please have look on JS fundamental.

Comment: i used getElementById means that get the element by its id and i used 3 id

Comment: Yeah, get **element** by ID. Not **elements**. --- Use a class for multiple elements, that's basic HTML.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, look like you tried to tell me something which is not related to this question. If i am wrong you have provide more input here. Don't be sad i am here to learn to any one.

Comment: but why its show undefined just clarify me? I have no clue in which portion the code is not working

Comment: @Janny - no, I meant you gave the OP a burn (as it was funny).

Comment: first of all just look at my code it has 3 textboxes which contain name as well as id like name="qty1" id="qty".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3jqwfac8/ - This fiddle shows that when you have multiple elements with the same ID, only the first is returned using `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code I understood that you want to have total of values in your table rows.

One important thing that went wrong is, that **`id`s of elements should be unique.**

But You have given the same `id` to all the `input`s. Maybe what you are looking for is a **`class`**. You can give a common class to the common operation elements and use for your purpose.

Here, take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8xoac5z/)

```js
function sumVals() {
  var row = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(row[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById("sum").value = total;
}
```

```html
<input class="qty" name="qty1" />
<input class="qty" name="qty2" />
<input class="qty" name="qty3" />
<button onclick="sumVals()">
  Add
</button>
<input id="sum" />
```